# SQL convert to 00.00%?

Tags: sql, excel, percentage

This is probably a silly question but I have the following query which extracts data in the following format.

```
0.00
6.67
```

and so on. I want these to go into excel as `06.67%` and `0.00%`. The `0`'s are working fine however the `6.67%` is just giving me `667.00%`

It's probably something minor I am missing here but can someone please help?

Thanks in advance :)

```
convert(
    decimal(5,2),
    (100 * convert(float,DNAs) / convert(float,SumofAppointments))
) AS 'DNA Percentage
```

Comment: What is SQL?....Answer: structured query language.  Why doesn't that tag help?  Because it doesn't indicate *what flavor of SQL*... what is your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing this through MS Query, you should only need to do two things:

1. Drop the multiplication by 100 within your SQL
2. Format the column as a percentage -- Excel will render 0.12 as 12%

From that point forward, any time you refresh your MS Query Object / Table / Listobject, it will retain any formatting changes you made.